# presenting a modal view over a splitView

Tags: iphone, ipad, modal-dialog, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm having a problem making a universal app... In the application delegate I set up the main navigation for ipad and iphone:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
 window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[ [UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
 if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
// The device is an iPad running iPhone 3.2 or later.
  [self putSplitView];
 } else {
  [self putTabBar];
 }
 [window makeKeyAndVisible]; 
 return YES;
}

- (void)putSplitView {
 RootiPadViewController *rootiPadViewController = [[RootiPadViewController alloc] init];
 UISplitViewController *splitController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
 splitController.viewControllers = [NSArray 
        arrayWithObjects:rootiPadViewController.seccionesView,
                         rootiPadViewController.noticiasView, 
                         nil];
    [window addSubview:splitController.view];
}

- (void)putTabBar {
 TabBarController *tabBar = [[TabBarController alloc] init];
 [window addSubview:tabBar.view];
}
```

RootiPadViewController is in charge of loading data an generating the panes for the splitView, so that its initialization incorporates a modalView with a loader, such that:

```
@implementation RootiPadViewController

@synthesize seccionesView, noticiasView;

- (id)init {
 if ((self = [super init])) {
  SeccionesVC_iPad *sec = [[SeccionesVC_iPad alloc] init];
  NoticiasVC_iPad *not = [[NoticiasVC_iPad alloc] init];
  self.noticiasView = not;
  self.seccionesView = sec;
  Init *initVC = [[Init alloc] init];
  [self presentModalViewController:initVC animated:YES];
 }
 return self;
}
```

The code compiles without warnings, but for some reason the loadView method of initVC is never called and the modal view doesn't appear...

Any ideas why this might be happening? 
thanks for your help!

Antonio

Answer (score 2):

I know this is last year's question, but while I think I found the cause, I'm still trying to figure out a good non-hack solution for dealing with this.

Assuming you're working for iPad:

Upon initialization, splitViewController Master's viewDidLoad is called first, then the Detail's viewDidLoad.

If you attempt to put a modal window initializer in the Master's viewDidLoad, nothing seems to happen: This is because the Detail's viewDidLoad has executed after your modal view's viewDidLoad, resulting in your modal view being hidden away.

Breakpointing the modal view class, I see it enter initWithNibName in the modal view. I don't use ARC and here I assume your modal view doesn't dealloc until the program quits - The modal view is still there, but there's no way to get to it.

In iPhone: 
Disregard this - because there is NO splitViewController for the iPhone. In fact, the default Universal splitViewController project treats the Master and Detail view as separate pages. So at application init, all you have to worry about is the Master viewDidLoad.

This is why, in a Universal project, pushing a modal view in viewDidLoad works as intended in the iPhone emulator, but NEVER in the iPad emulator.

Note that this only applies during the viewDidLoad stage; if you push a modal view AFTER viewDidLoad into the Master window, the modal view works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should present your modal ViewController from the RootViewController 'ViewDidLoad' method, instead of the 'init' method... Not sure the view hierarchy is created that soon